# Encountering Proxy Path Issue While Attempting to Download and Run 'Windscribe-Checker' Tool in Termux on Android

Tags: android, github, terminal, termux

Title: Issue with Downloading and Opening "Windscribe-Checker" Tool in Termux (Android) - Proxy Path Problem

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm facing an issue while attempting to download and open the tool available at "https://github.com/Plasmonix/Windscribe-Checker" within the Termux terminal on my Android device. Unfortunately, I've encountered an error message that I'm struggling to resolve. The error message I received can be viewed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B1tN.jpg).

The error seems to be related to a proxy path problem, but I'm uncertain about the specific steps I should take to address this issue. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or insights from those who might have encountered a similar problem or have expertise in this area.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!